# Why does the state variable become undefined when the value is changed in the dropdown menu react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here is the table I'm trying to create:

[image]

When I change the value of the dropdown bars, the value becomes undefined and I don't understand why. But initially, when I click submit, it works and the alert pops up with both of the default values I set in `this.state`.

This is what the alert looks like when I change the SDG:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
import React from 'react'

class Dropdown extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        sdg: 'SDG 1: No Poverty',
        assignment_type: 1
    };
  
      this.handleSDGChange = this.handleSDGChange.bind(this);
      this.handleAssignmentChange = this.handleAssignmentChange.bind(this);
      this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }
    
    // Handling all 3 input changes
    handleSDGChange(event) {
      this.setState({sdg: event.target.sdg});
    }

    handleAssignmentChange(event) {
        this.setState({assignment_type: event.target.assignment_type});
    }

    // Handling all 3 input submissions
    handleSubmit(event) {
        console.log(this.state.sdg)
      alert(this.state.sdg + '--- Assignment Type: ' + this.state.assignment_type);
      event.preventDefault();
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
            <label>SDG:</label>
            <select value={this.state.sdg} onChange={this.handleSDGChange}>
              <option value="SDG 1: No Poverty">SDG 1: No Poverty</option>
              <option value="SDG 2: Zero Hunger">SDG 2: Zero Hunger</option>
              <option value="SDG 3: Good Health & Well Being">SDG 3: Good Health & Well Being</option>
            </select>

            <label>Assignment Type:</label>
            <select value={this.state.assignment_type} onChange={this.handleAssignmentChange}>
              <option value="1">1: Discussion Project</option>
              <option value="2">2: PDF Case study</option>
              <option value="3">3: Community Project</option>
            </select>

            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
      );
    }
  }
export default Dropdown
```

Comment: `event.target` is the `<option>` element that the user has selected - it's not clear why you expect this to have properties called `sdg` or `assignment_type`...

Comment: (I think you simply want `event.target.value` in both of these handlers)

Comment: Tested this and  @RobinZigmond is correct.  Changing `event.target.sdg` to `event.target.value` resolves the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to change your `event.target.sdg` and `event.target.assignment_type` to `event.target.value`. `event.target` does not have those properties, those are simply the variables you defined in your `this.state`, if you want to access the value of the event of each of the handlers, you use `.value`.